# Publish photo from Camera to Facebook Page in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios4, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Facebook iOS SDK 3.0  in iOS 4+. 
I want to publish a Photo (either from my camera or from the stored photos in my ios device) to the wall in Facebook.

I have checked http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/ the documentation but I did not find the amswer.

Any help?

Comment: Go here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/ search for image and it should provide you with the information you need.

Comment: He loads an ImageView from an URL. Does it work if I load the image view from the stored images or the camera?

Comment: It appears you can only display a picture if you provide the url. Which means you have to upload it to a server of some sort first then provide a link. "Picture: The URL of a picture attached to this post. The picture must be at least 50px by 50px and have a maximum aspect ratio of 3:1"

Comment: On a positive note, if you are an apple developer, I believe what you are trying to do becomes considerably easier in iOS 6....about as much as I can say without breaking Apple disclosure rules.

Comment: I cant believe that there isn't an easy way to post to Facebook from ios sdk just by attaching a binary stream or something like that :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you are looking for is here. Remember in iOS 6 this will be very easy....but for now.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdk-reference/iossdk/3.0/class/FBRequest/#//api/name/requestForUploadPhoto:

Here is example code:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/#step5

Answer (score 0):

sheet view composer for posting on the wall http://www.developers-life.com/facebook-compose-view.html
just published for everyone

Comment: iOS 6 is not officially released yet so this blog post is breaking the Apple agreement.

Comment: i don't use any solutions from iOS 6, i just did controller looks like in iOS 6. based on the picture which I saw on some news site

Answer (score 0):

Check Scrumptious Sample as part of our SDK. It has the exact thing you need.

Answer (score 0):

From FB documentation : The best way to publish image (for iOS 6.x) :

```
- (void)publishToFacebook:(UIImage*)image {
    BOOL displayedNativeDialog =
    [FBNativeDialogs
        presentShareDialogModallyFrom:uiViewController
        initialText:@""
        image:image
        url:[NSURL URLWithString:shortURL]
        handler:^(FBNativeDialogResult result, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                /* handle failure */
                NSLog(@"FB Error");
            } else {
                if (result == FBNativeDialogResultSucceeded) {
                    /* handle success */
                    NSLog(@"FB Success");
                } else {
                    /* handle user cancel */
                    NSLog(@"FB Cancel");
                }
            }
        }];

    if (!displayedNativeDialog) {
        NSLog(@"no Native Support");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"FBPublishErrorTitle", @"") message:NSLocalizedString(@"FBPublishError", @"") delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```